# Unexpected token ) at createScript (vm.js:56:10) Node js when running gulp dev only on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, gulp

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\server\index.js:2:13)
```

I am getting this error when i run gulp dev 
This happens only on windows , it is running fine in linux and the server is getting started on linux

Below is the Snippet

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const routes = require('./routes');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdb');
const dbConnection = mongoose.connection;
dbConnection.on(
    'error',
     console.error.bind(console, 'Connection Error:')
);
dbConnection.once(
    'open',
     () => {
         console.log('DB connection successful');
     }
);
```

I get this error at 12th line ,

However when i write it this way
I won't get any error and server starts

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const routes = require('./routes');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ecommerce');
const dbConnection = mongoose.connection;
dbConnection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Connection Error:'));
dbConnection.once('open',()=>{console.log('DB connection successful');});
```

What is the reason behind this ?

Comment: What version of node are you running on Windows?  The `() => { ... }` arrow function notation is new(ish), so if you're running an older node version on windows... it won't work.

Comment: i am using node 6.11.2 and npm  3.10.10

Comment: if it does not work , why is it working in the other way, even that is an arrow function

Comment: You said it works on Linux, but not on Windows.  Are you running 6.11.2 on both?  Is any of the code running through babel, do you have a global/local babel config, is it the same on both platforms?

Comment: Thanks @searlea , I used nvm and downloaded node 8.9.1 and ran gulp dev on the server folder, It ran fine. I had diff versions running on linux and windows latter one being old

Comment: That's great, thanks for the update.  BTW, if you ever have any issues with nvm, give [nvs](https://github.com/jasongin/nvs) a try instead.

Comment: Try to rewrite the arrow function in ES5 style. It should help you.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue, so i just deleted the bloc of code that was causing the error, and rewrite it, i think it's due to some hidden characters

Answer (score 0):

If somebody falls in this error, major problem is with your node version. Upgrade it to the latest one.